# How Do I solve this further? Logic (Fitch)

Tags: logic

This is what I have done
[image: This is what I have done][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6izuJ.png)

This is edit 2
[image: Edit 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your set-up is excellent!

Second, note that if $Smaller(b,a)$ is true, then $Larger(a,b)$ should be true as well. However, this does not follow *logically*, but by the meaning of the predicates. So, you'll have to use Ana Con, which understands the meaning of the predicates.

Comment: Hey!
I tried to use Ana Con but Fitch says that I can't use that.
The book says (You may use Ana Con but only involving literals and ⊥)

Comment: @jkmnjik Ok, so you can use ANA Con to derive $Larger(a,b)$ from $Smaller(b,a)$

Comment: I used Ana Con in Edit2

Comment: Huh! That should work!  You used the problem set-up file provided by the software, rather than that you created your own file from scratch?

Comment: I created my own and that's the reason it's not working.

Comment: I copy pasted the solution in the set-up file and it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jkmnjik Yay!  Yeah, always use the provided set-up files!